# Graph works on first tabitem but not second tabitem?

Tags: c#, wpf, charts, wpftoolkit, data-binding

I am using Wpf Toolkit for the graph, and I realise that it doesn't work when I place it as the second tabitem. What could be the problem?

This is my graph:

```
<TabControl>
    <TabItem Header="PowerFlow">
    </TabItem>
    <TabItem Header="Graph" Name="Graphs">
        <ScrollViewer HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" 
VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" Margin="0,-28,0,28">
            <Grid Height="921" Background="DarkGray">
                <chartingToolkit:Chart  Name="lineChart" Title="Power Graph" Background="YellowGreen" Foreground="DarkBlue"                   
               VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="16,36,20,0" Height="432"  IsEnabled="True" >
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title="SolarCell"     
    ItemsSource="{Binding}" DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" 
    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
         IsSelectionEnabled="True" DataContext="{Binding}">
                        <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                            <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Power (W)"></chartingToolkit:LinearAxis>
                        </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
                </chartingToolkit:Chart>
                <Button Content="Refresh" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="718,391,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" />
                <TextBox Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="696,73,0,0" Name="textBox7" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="97" Loaded="textBox7_Loaded" />
                <Label Content="Time started:" Height="28" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="606,73,0,0" Name="label1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="84" />
            </Grid>
        </ScrollViewer>
    </TabItem>
</TabControl>
</Window>
```

and the code behind:

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>> Power = new ObservableCollection<KeyValuePair<double, double>>();
    double i = 0;

    public MainWindow()
    {

        InitializeComponent();
        TabItem Graphs = new TabItem();
        DispatcherTimer timer = new DispatcherTimer();
        timer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);  // per 5 seconds, you could change it
        timer.Tick += new EventHandler(timer_Tick);
        timer.IsEnabled = true;
    }



    Random random = new Random(DateTime.Now.Millisecond);
    void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        Power.Add(new KeyValuePair<double, double>(i, random.NextDouble()));
        i += 5;
        lineChart.DataContext = Power;

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Can you define what happens when you put it in the 2nd tab item? "Doesn't work" could mean any number of things

Answer (score 2):

If you remove the line

```
DataContext="{Binding}"
```

from the LineSeries it should work. 
Unfortunately I can't explain why it isn't working. But as DataContexts are usually derived in the control hierarchy it isn't necessary at this point and somehow leads to this strange issue.

HTH

Comment: It couldn't work at all if I removed that line from the LineSeries, even in the first tabitem. Thanks though.

Comment: hmmm strange, in my case its working fine. 
As soon as I remove the line the chart is plotted fine.

              <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title="SolarCell" 
                  ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                  DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                  IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                  IsSelectionEnabled="True" 
                >