# Cannot get the WPFToolkit chart to show data (throws an exception)

Tags: c#, wpf, charts

After a few hours of unsuccessful attempts, I hope someone helps me here. I followed a post showing how to simply display data in WPFToolkit lineChart:

So I have the chart:

```
<chartingToolkit:Chart x:Name="myChart" Title="Power Graph" Background="YellowGreen" 
                             Foreground="DarkBlue" VerticalAlignment="Top" Margin="16,36,20,0" Height="432"  IsEnabled="True">
                <chartingToolkit:LineSeries Title="SolarCell"  
                                    ItemsSource="{Binding}" 
                                    DependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Value}" 
                                    IndependentValueBinding="{Binding Path=Key}"
                                    IsSelectionEnabled="True">
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
                        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="X" Title="Time (Mins)" Interval="5"  />
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.IndependentAxis>
                    <chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                        <chartingToolkit:LinearAxis Orientation="Y" Title="Power (W)"/>
                    </chartingToolkit:LineSeries.DependentRangeAxis>
                </chartingToolkit:LineSeries>
            </chartingToolkit:Chart>
```

and the C# code:

```
Dictionary<string, float> a = new Dictionary<string, float>();
this.myChart.DataContext = a;

void timer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.a.Add(this.elapsedTime.ToString(),meter.GetResult());
           elapsedTime++;

        }
```

When run, I got the following exception:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Windows.Controls.DataVisualization.Toolkit.dll
>
> Additional information: Assigned independent axis cannot be used. This
>   may be due to an unset Orientation property for the axis.

Comment: Related thread : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631049/assigned-independent-axis-cannot-be-used-this-may-be-due-to-an-unset-orientatio

Comment: Related AND solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7673147/graph-works-on-first-tabitem-but-not-second-tabitem?rq=1 Use DispatcherTimer and ObservableCollection